# Global Variable in Laravel 8

Tags: global-variables, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 8. I need a Global variable which will be available in all Views (Blade files).

This Global variable will update using some API call with every route call.

How can I create this Global Variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your global variables in AppServiceProvider in boot method:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $value = "myGlobal";
        View::share('key', $value);
    }
```

read this documentation : [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)